# Input field is not accepting characters

Tags: html, reactjs

Trying to authenticate a user login, but whenever "value="{}" is entered, it doesn't displays any value inside the field area.

class Login extends Component{

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        email:"",
        password:"",
        fireErrors:"",
        formTitle: "Login",
        loginBtn: true
    }
}

handleChange = e =>{
    this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
}
```

....

```
<input  type="text"  onClick={this.handleChange} value={this.state.email} name="email"/>
```

Comment: please mark as answer if the solution worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `onClick={this.handleChange}` to `onChange={this.handleChange}`

Because `this.handleChange` was triggered when you click only

Comment: great to hear that.